# Add a Virtual Network to a Cloud Service in Azure

Tags: azure, azure-cloud-services, azure-virtual-network, virtual-network

I would like to associate/add a **Virtual Network** to a **Cloud Service in Azure.**

I have found a solution where you can download and edit the Cloud Service's configuration file and upload it back in order to add a Virtual Network. But the solution only works if the Cloud Service is **NEW** and only about to be created

However, I am trying to look for ways on how to add a Virtual Network to an already **existing/running Azure Cloud Service**.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, this is not possible, whenever you want to include a cloud service on Microsoft Azure to a Network you should do it at the time it gets created, that's why it's recommended to START your project while putting all of your resources on the same network and in the same region.